# Converting integer to binary with variable number of bits

Tags: python

I want to pick a number from a given list `list` and extract the places of ones from `n` bits representation.

I know that if I want 8 bits, I need to write

```
r = random.choice(list)
bin = "{0:08b}".format(r)
```

but I want to do something like

```
bin = "{0:0(self.n)b}".format(r)
```

where `n` is a class member.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested a `{…}` to define the size:

```
bin = "{0:0{1}b}".format(r, self.n)
```

And with Py2.7+ you can omit the numbers if you find that cleaner:

```
bin = "{:0{}b}".format(r, self.n)
```

For example:

```
>>> "{:0{}b}".format(9, 8)
'00001001'
```

Answer (score 1):

From python3.6 on you will be able to use [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), adding the variable names to your string.

```
In [81]: pad,num = 8,9

In [82]: f"{num:0{pad}b}"
Out[82]: '00001001'
```

Using str.format, you can also use names:

```
In [92]: pad,num = 8,9

In [93]: "{n:0{p}b}".format(n=num, p=pad)
Out[93]: '00001001'
```

Comment: And I thought the [PEP for this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) was a candidate for an April Fools joke ...

Comment: Although NB: 3.6 won't be released [until the end of 2016](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0494/#release-schedule)